# Turf.js only with Mapbox.js?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, turf

After trying turf.js with plain ole leaflet and getting confused because the most basic stuff wouldn't work, I'm thinking that turf.js requires Mapbox.js and access token.  Can anyone confirm or deny this??

If this is the case, I have either totally overlooked it on [the turf github](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf) and [the turf API site](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/), or that information is nowhere to be found, which is kind of annoying.

Comment: For what I know...this should not require Mapbox.js nor the token. I'm interested in also knowing this. If it depends on Mapbox infrastructure...well.

Comment: I wouldn't think so either... I've got to look in to it more.

Comment: We're happy to help with any turf-related questions [on the issue tracker](https://github.com/turfjs/turf/issues) if you can provide code examples of what's not working with Leaflet.

Answer (score 10):

Turf.js is ***not*** dependent on Mapbox.js or access token.  I was initially confused with the documentation, I think, but it works fine with plain leaflet.js.

Answer (score 6):

Turf has no visualization dependencies at all. It does not require any map display, and works with raw GeoJSON data. For example, I often use Turf on my desktop (via Node.js) for running analysis that outputs the results to files I open in QGIS. The code runs 100% on your machine, so there are no access tokens or servers involved anywhere in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Turf.js does not require Mapbox map or Mapbox access token. It can be intergrated well with leaflet, which I have tried and it worked. Also it can be integrated with ArcGIS JS API too.